# How to check if event has been fired in another form/class

Tags: vb.net, winforms, events, visual-studio-2013

So putting it as simply as possible, I have one class which opens a form from inside sub like so:

```
Public Sub LoadExtension()

    'various code...

    Dim form as new frmMain
    frmMain.ShowDialog()

    'various code...

End Sub
```

And inside this form I have two buttons, one will just close the form, so the LoadExtension() sub will continue. The other button I want to use to 'exit' the LoadExtension() sub inside the main class so that loading stops completely. The button event inside the form module is like so:

```
Private Sub btnStopLoad_click(sender as object, e as eventargs) handles btnStopLoad.click
    'exit the LoadExtension sub somehow
End sub
```

What is the simplest way to achieve this? I thought I could do something like this in the LoadExtension() sub (after the .ShowDialog):

```
If frmMain.btnStopLoad.clicked then
    Exit Sub
End If
```

But it won't let me do that from the class module, apparently I need to use 'raise event' or something? I'm not very familiar with the way that events work. Can someone offer me an easy solution? I'd be very grateful. I've been looking around the web for a solution but haven't had any success. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting the `DialogResult` of the `frmMain`.

```
Public Class frmMain
    Inherits Form

    Private Sub _ButtonContinueClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonContinue.Click
        Me.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ButtonExitClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonExit.Click
        Me.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Then change the `LoadExtension` method to something like this:

```
Public Sub LoadExtension()

    'various code...

    Using form As New frmMain()
        If (form.ShowDialog() <> Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End Using

    'various code...

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use dialogresult to let the LoadExtension function know which button was pressed.

Answer (score 1):

DialogResult is what you are looking for - the standard way to do it.

You can, however, subscribe to events of another form's controls, like this:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
  Dim frm As New Form2
  AddHandler frm.Button1.Click, AddressOf OtherFormButton_Click
  frm.ShowDialog()
End Sub

Private Sub OtherFormButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)
  MessageBox.Show("hello")
End Sub
```

This is assuming `Form2` has a button named `Button1`.